# Haskell get directories in directory

Tags: haskell

How can I get a list of directories that are in a directory?

I've come up with the below, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way:

```
import System.Directory
import qualified Filesystem.Path as FsP
import Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS
import Control.Monad

getDirectories :: Prelude.FilePath -> IO [Prelude.FilePath]
getDirectories x = do
  listDirectory x
  >>= (return . fmap decodeString)
  >>= return . fmap (FsP.append (decodeString x))
  >>= (return . fmap encodeString)
  >>= filterM doesDirectoryExist
```

Comment: Do you need the `do` notation when you already use `>>=` operator?

Comment: You're correct it's not needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are using the package [system-filepath](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.13.4) which is deprecated, how about using the [filepath](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.1.2) package instead:

```
import           Control.Monad    (filterM)
import           System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, listDirectory)
import           System.FilePath  ((</>))

getDirectories :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getDirectories filePath = do
  allFiles <- listDirectory filePath
  filterM (doesDirectoryExist . (filePath </>)) allFiles
```

Or if you prefer explicitly using the bind operator:

```
import           Control.Monad    (filterM)
import           System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, listDirectory)
import           System.FilePath  ((</>))

getDirectories :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getDirectories filePath = listDirectory filePath
                      >>= filterM (doesDirectoryExist . (filePath </>))
```

**NOTE**: Your version of the function will return the input filepath prepended to every output directory in the list. While this might be what you want, the version of `getDirectories` I am giving you may be more general as it behaves exactly like `listDirectory` and simply prunes the files/executables.

**EDIT**: Changed the import from `System.FilePath.Posix` to `System.FilePath` for true platform independence. Thanks to [Justin Raymond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086778/haskell-get-directories-in-directory/44087266#comment75202698_44087313) for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is `System.Directory`.

```
import Control.Monad (filterM)
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, getCurrentDirectory, getDirectoryContents)

listDirs :: IO [FilePath]
listDirs = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents >>= filterM doesDirectoryExist
```

If you want to pass the filepath as argument, just doen't use `getCurrentDirectory`.

```
import Control.Monad (filterM)
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, getCurrentDirectory)

listDirs :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
listDirs path = getDirectoryContents path >>= filterM (doesDirectoryExist . (++) path)
```

Comment: The example with `getCurrentDirectory` should work, however the other one won't. `getDirectoryContents` gives you the content in relative filepaths not absolute!

Comment: @basil-henry fixed

Comment: Well you are now missing the path separator "/" or "\" (on Windows). In my solution I use `(</>)` from the `filepath` package to do the platform dependent appending of the path.

Comment: you just pass it as an argument. `foo/` instead of `foo`. bfd. and if you want to get pedantic, you should import `System.FilePath` instead of `System.FilePath.Posix` for true platform independence.

Comment: Fair enough! :)